# Django - difficult order by (two M2M relations)

Tags: python, django

I have such situation:

```
class X(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Z(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Y(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    xs = models.ManyToManyField(X, null=True, blank=True)
    zs = models.ManyToManyField(Z, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to get all `X` objects and order them by `Z` `number` field.

Objects where there are no related Y or where their Y's have no related Z should be removed.

Is it possible to do it with Django, using acceptable count of SQL queries? Or I need to execute raw SQL query?

Example output:

```
| X.name   | Y.name     | Z.number
-----------------------------------
| x2       | y1         |  100
|          |            |  200
|          |-----------------------
|          | y2         |  100
|          |-----------------------
|          | y3         |  500
|----------------------------------
| x1       | y1         |  100
|          |            |  200
|          |-----------------------
|          | y4         |  400
|          |            |  100
|----------------------------------
| x3       | y5         |  300
```

x2 first because of y3 with z = 500.
x1 second because of y4 with z = 400.
x3 last because of y5 with z = 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

X.objects.annotate(max_z=Max('y__zs__number')).order_by('max_z')
```